# Check element in a list

Tags: ocaml

I have an example:

```
let l  = [0;1;2]
let l1 = [0;2]
```

From the list `l` check that whether or not there are some element of `l` is belong to `l1`; if yes then return a list of pair, for instance `[(1,0); (1;2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you should iterate through each element in l. Then check if the first element of l is an element of l1. If it is, filter out all the elements that are equal. Then get the length of list of equal elements which will be the first character in the tuple that will go into the return list.

```
let check_list l l1 =
  let rec check l l1 combined = 
    match l with
    |[] -> combined
    |(h::t) -> if (List.mem h l1) then 
        check t l1 ((List.length(List.filter (fun x -> h=x) l1),h)::combined)
            else check t l1 combined
in check l l1 []
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?
Counting the number of occurrences of each element from `l` in `l1`?

One idea might be to ask yourself, how do I do it for one element of `l`?
For this purpose, you might want to make a function with the following signature: `nb_mem : 'a -> 'a list -> int`.

Then to produce your list, you could do it recursively.

```
let rec check l l1 =
  match l with
  | []     -> []
  | e :: r -> let nb = nb_mem e l1 in
              if nb = 0 then check r l1 else (nb,e) :: (check r l1)
```

Of course, this doesn't take into account the fact that an element might appear several times in `l` and is far from being optimal.

One idea might be to sort both of your lists (in case you are working with integer values it is easy) before to avoid reading `l1` entirely multiple times.

You could also go for a `hashtbl` containing the number of occurrences of each element in `l1` and then producing your list by reading the corresponding entries for each element of `l`.